# login system: different errors in different browers php

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to develop a login system. This is my file that checks if the user is logged in or not:

```
<?php 
require_once("config.inc.php"); 

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['username']) ) { header('location:' . $website_url . '/home.php'); }
?>

<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Tirane");
$todaydate3 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$myusername7=$_POST['usernameform']; 
$mypassword7=$_POST['passwordform'];

$myusername7=stripslashes($myusername7);
$mypassword7=stripslashes($mypassword7);

$myusername7=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $myusername7);
$mypassword7=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $mypassword7);

$encrypted_mypassword234=hash('sha512', $mypassword7);

$logimi46 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername7' AND password = '$encrypted_mypassword234' AND oauth_provider != 'facebook' AND verifikuar = 'po'");
$logimi225 = mysqli_num_rows($logimi46);

if($logimi225 > '0') {

$myusername71=$_POST['usernameform'];
$myusername71=stripslashes($myusername71);
$myusername71=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $myusername71);

$mypassword71=$_POST['passwordform'];
$mypassword71=stripslashes($mypassword71);
$mypassword71=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $mypassword71);
$encrypted_mypassword231=hash('sha512', $mypassword71);

$tedhenateperdoruesit21=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername71' AND password = '$encrypted_mypassword231' AND oauth_provider != 'facebook' AND verifikuar = 'po'");
$userdata2 = mysqli_fetch_array($tedhenateperdoruesit21);

session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $userdata2['id'];
$_SESSION['oauth_id'] = "nuk_ka_id";
$_SESSION['username'] = $userdata2['username'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $userdata2['email'];
$_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = "log_in_form";

if($userdata2['disabled'] == "po") {  
$sqlcojejo = "UPDATE users SET disabled = 'jo' WHERE username = '$myusername7'";
$querycojejo = mysqli_query($con, $sqlcojejo);
} 

header("Location: " . $website_url . "/checkifloggedin.php");

} else {

header("Location: " . $website_url . "/signup.php?action=loginerror");
exit();

}

?>
```

Now, my problem is that if I try to login with google chrome, it works and I login my website, but if I try with firefox, it does not log me in, but redirects me to `signup.php?action=loginerror` and I try to login in these 2 different browers with the same account details.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: PHP has nothing AT ALL to do with your browser. It's a server side language. As long as your server stays the same, this has absolutely nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: This is probably a HTML/Browser issue, not PHP.

Comment: You're comparing the number of rows to string `'0'`, rather than a number `0`. That's not good. Also indenting your code properly would help... And naming variables in a sane way and not duplicating them (myusername7 / myusername71)

Comment: Use firebug to analyze the post data and see what it's sending to php.

Comment: @Tushar any idea how to solve this problem since it has nothing to do with php?

Comment: @viraptor I did what you said, but still doesn't work... :/

Comment: @DjOnce That was not re. the bug itself. More of a "I can't even see what you're trying to do if the code is that crazy". The problem is likely not in the php code anyway. Since you're not coding in English, I'd have a look at the encoding - maybe one of the browsers is set to different keyboard layout, or something silly like that.